# Is there a hotkey in Visual Studio to open the member drop down list?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, keyboard-shortcuts

In Visual Studio there is a drop down list in the top right hand corner that you can use to navigate to the various members in the class. Does anyone know if there is a hot key to open this ddl?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I think you're looking for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, which moves the cursor to the navigation bar at the top of a code view. From there, you can press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to move the cursor over to the member list.

For this (and pretty much every other Visual Studio hotkey/shortcut key combination), see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx).

Comment: Why they don't have resharper-like alt-\ which lets you search the member list quickly I can't imagine.  Ctrl-F2 tab tab sucks and it's not even a decent search.

Comment: This indeed quite a terrible omission. Couple this with VS's support for programmable user-macros being taken away in previous versions, you can't even patch your way around this yourself.

Comment: @JohnOpincar They do now, see my answer.

Answer (score 12):

Visual Studio 2017+: They now support Resharper-like shortcuts. They work pretty well, too.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> - 'Go to All' (class/member/file), type `m MyProp` for members only
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> - 'Go to Member in current file'

[image]

Comment: Ctrl+,(Global) is also used by 'Edit.GoToAll' Is this just me? Anyway, Thanks!

Comment: In Visual Studio 2022, it seems Alt + \ searches members in the entire solution instead of current file

Answer (score 8):

Using VS 2008, I still don't know how to get directly to the Members dropdown which is what I want.  But, the key bindings will be different for everyone.  The command you want to search for under ***Options > Keyboard > Show commands containing:*** is ***Window.MoveToNavigationBar***.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using the default keybindings packaged with Visual Studio, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> will focus the top-right drop-down list, and you can then navigate members by pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> and using the arrow keys.

Answer (score 2):

In my install of VS 2013, this is called Window.MoveToNaviationBar and is bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>. This is visual C++ settings.

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> to get up there, then a click on <kbd>Tab</kbd> will get you to the member list instead of the object list.