# Shortcut to navigate members in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

On top of  visual studio code editor, There are two drop down lists displays list  of classes and members in then selected class. See the picture below. What do you call them and what are the shortcuts? So that I can navigate to methods and members using keyboard.

I am using Vs 2010

Thanks

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a hotkey in Visual Studio to open the member drop down list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454642/is-there-a-hotkey-in-visual-studio-to-open-the-member-drop-down-list)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can use Edit -> Navigate to [Ctrl + ,]. or Solution Navigator in Vs Power Tools. But I am still looking for shortcut to access it directly.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> gets you there. Take a look at this link. [Is there a hotkey in Visual Studio to open the member drop down list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454642/is-there-a-hotkey-in-visual-studio-to-open-the-member-drop-down-list)

Answer (score 8):

Not strictly on topic but ReSharper has a shortcut for this <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is Edit.ExpandCollapsableBaseTypeList (or something) in the Tools-Options-Keyboard.
If that doesn't work you can always record a macro and assign a shortcut key for that.