# Access dropdown list in package manager console

Tags: visual-studio, hotkeys

I'm trying to reduce my mouse usage in Visual Studio. Until now I haven't been able to access the drop down lists in the "Package Manager Console" - see the attached picture.

[image: Screenshot]

The letter "k" in "Paketquelle" is underlined, but pressing Alt+K or any combos of Tab+Modifier key will not focus the drop-down lists. Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454642/is-there-a-hotkey-in-visual-studio-to-open-the-member-drop-down-list) I tried Ctrl+F2 for no good. Any ideas?

PS: Unfortunately I have to use the localized german version, but this should not be a problem.

Comment: It is Version 14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, I feel retarded now. A simple Shift+Alt+K did the trick. You can then cycle the bar with Tabulator, putting the focus back on the console by pressing Esc.